# MSSQL Avg of two int.Max is int.Max + 1. Why?

Tags: sql-server

Strange behaviour became visible during a unit test.

An int table in mssql has two entries, each of them int.Max (2147483647).
Calling AVG() on it will cause an overflow error, but there is the possibility to cast the values to double and then compute average on it. So command looks like this:

```
Select Avg(Cast(TestModel.IntProperty as Real)) from dbo.TestModel
```

The expected average of (double)2147483647 and (double)2147483647 is (double)2147483647.

But the result returned by mssql with the given select query is 214748364**8**. Why?

[image]

Used SQL Server 2016 Management Studio for testing.

MSSQL version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)

Edit: `Real` is not the appropriate type to cast to in this scenario. With a cast to `Float` 2147483647 is returned. Float is fine for my scenario, but as mentioned in the accepted answer, decimal or bigint may be more appropriate in usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you're using `real`, which can only hold 7 digits (your value has 10).

If you run `CONVERT(real,2147483647)` you'll find that the return value is `2.147484E+09`. As a `bigint` that value is `2147483648` ***not*** `2147483647`.

Use an appropriate data type and this isn't a problem:

```
SELECT AVG(r) AS r, AVG(i) AS i
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(real,2147483647),CONVERT(bigint,2147483647)),
            (CONVERT(real,2147483647),CONVERT(bigint,2147483647)))V(r,i);
```

Notice `r` returns `2147483648`, but `i` returns `2147483647`.

`float` also won't suffer this, as `float` can store more digits. As per [float and real (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) a `real` is made up of 7 digits, and a `float` has 14 digits. `2147483647` is 10 digits long, so some accuracy ***will*** be lost when you use `real`; it has to be as it can't store 10 digits. I still, however, suggest not using a floating point data type unless you *really* need to.

*Note, it's not "+1" either. If you use the value `2147483649` and insert it into a `real` you get the value `2147483648` too when you convert it back to an integer. If you run the below, you'll actually see that **every** number returned is `2147483648` for the `real` data type, even though there are actually 100 different values:*

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 51 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2)
SELECT 2147483647-I AS o,
       CONVERT(real,2147483647-I) AS r,
       CONVERT(bigint,CONVERT(real,2147483647-I)) AS i
FROM Tally T
ORDER BY T.I;
```

Comment: Reading MSSQL documentaion more carefully would have helped me. I know the precision problem of floating points, but living in c# world, falsely assumed, that float is the smaller of the two floating types... and casted to real, assuming that it must be the bigger one *shame* Thanks to ORM, the database stuff is abstracted away not only in the code, but also largely in the mind :b